# Aquatic Star Database: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

im trying to add a foreign key to my database and it's not allowing me.. 
Alter table `aquaticstar`.`schedule`
  add foreign key (`username`) references `aquaticstar`.`staff`(`username`)

i know theres a lot of posts similar to this but ive read them and nothing seems to be working... im using windows 32- bits... sqlyog is the gui for my database and wampserver... i put the sql for my database in pastebin... i didnt want to clutter the question...

http://pastebin.com/TPqdSucJ

pls let me know what is wrong and pls let me know if you need any other information...

Comment: Are you using mysql with myISAM or InnoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using MyISAM default storage engine that does not support references.

Comment: @user1703514 Glad you've found the solution. You should have supplied more info about your configuration etc.. in the first place

Answer (score 0):

OHH MAN! I figured it out... so on my 2 tables i had different information... so in my schedule table, I'm supposed to have a column called username which is a foreign key to the staff table's primary key username... but on my schedule table i had usernames that were not found in my staff table... so that's why i got the error... i made sure all the usernames existed in my staff table.. and voila... it worked...
thnx guys for all the help anywaiz.. :)